# python3 convert files (from folder and sub folder) to json file on specific format(item include folder name and file name)

Tags: python, json, file, directory

python3 convert files (from folder and sub folder) to json file on specific format(item include folder name and file name)

i just can list file and directory

```
from os import walk
path = "F:\\stack\\sample"
for root, dirs, files in walk(path):
  print("folder：", dirs)
  print("file：", files)
  print("\n")
```

below is my folder and file structure

```
F:\stack\sample\EXA18902962\IM-2613-0001.jpg
F:\stack\sample\EXA18902962\IM-2613-0002.jpg
F:\stack\sample\EXA18902962\IM-2613-0003.jpg
F:\stack\sample\EXA18902962\IM-2613-0004.jpg
F:\stack\sample\EXA18902962\IM-2613-0005.jpg

F:\stack\sample\EXA18B01363\IM-2293-0001.jpg
F:\stack\sample\EXA18B01363\IM-2293-0002.jpg
F:\stack\sample\EXA18B01363\IM-2293-0003.jpg

F:\stack\sample\EXA18C05030\IM-0960-0001.jpg
F:\stack\sample\EXA18C05030\IM-0960-0002.jpg
F:\stack\sample\EXA18C05030\IM-0960-0003.jpg
F:\stack\sample\EXA18C05030\IM-0960-0004.jpg
F:\stack\sample\EXA18C05030\IM-0960-0005.jpg
F:\stack\sample\EXA18C05030\IM-0960-0006.jpg
F:\stack\sample\EXA18C05030\IM-0960-0007.jpg
F:\stack\sample\EXA18C05030\IM-0960-0008.jpg
```

hope output a json file like sample.json like below

```
{  
   "EXA18902962":[  
      "IM-2613-0001.jpg",
      "IM-2613-0002.jpg",
      "IM-2613-0003.jpg",
      "IM-2613-0004.jpg",
      "IM-2613-0005.jpg"
   ],
   "EXA18B01363":[  
      "IM-2293-0001.jpg",
      "IM-2293-0002.jpg",
      "IM-2293-0003.jpg"
   ],
   "EXA18C05030":[  
      "IM-0960-0001.jpg",
      "IM-0960-0002.jpg",
      "IM-0960-0003.jpg",
      "IM-0960-0004.jpg",
      "IM-0960-0005.jpg",
      "IM-0960-0006.jpg",
      "IM-0960-0007.jpg",
      "IM-0960-0008.jpg"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A robust way:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from os import path
import glob
import json

base_path = "F:\\stack\\sample"
d = defaultdict(list)

for file in glob.iglob(path.join(base_path, '*/*.jpg'), recursive=True):
  d[path.basename(path.dirname(file))].append(path.basename(file))

print(json.dumps(d))
# use json.dump to write json data into particular file
```